# How can I change dynamycally limit records per page using KNP Paginator Bundle?

Tags: symfony, pagination

Im using KNP Paginator Bundle, it works fine, but I cant make works the limit records per page (dynamically), I have readed and tried this post [Dynamic limit per page Knp Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295112/dynamic-limit-per-page-knp-pagination), but no luck.
Someone can help me?

Comment: `KNPPaginatorBundle` gives you an option to set the `limit`. You can set that value according to your logic. Can you please be more precise on your requirement and share some code?

Comment: Jeet, that option **limit** works very well, I need to let the user change it from the website, something like this: `<select name="maxItemPerPage" id="maxItemPerPage">
<option id="10">10</option>
<option id="20">20</option>
<option id="30">30</option>
</select>`, you know like bootstrap datatables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days of researching, I used bootstrap datatables classes and javascript functions to make work "limit per page" and "search input text" friendly to user.

Answer (score 0):

I answered in your other post too:

```
$pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $query, /* query NOT result */
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1)/*page number*/,
        10/*limit per page*/
);
```

The last parameter `10`, sets the number of items shown per page as I answered per your other post.

Comment: Alvin Bunk, the **limit** option works fine, but How can I let the user change it from the application? Also, I need to know how can I save Order, Limit per page or Filter if I go forward to some detail of the record and get back to the list?